# how to make my prefix works on lowercase and uppercase?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm really new on programming. can someone help me?
I made a discord bot, but my I can only use my prefix on lowercase, or just uppercase.
I wanna know how to make it works on both.

here's what I've tried. but it doesn't seems to work.. and now it's only work on lowercase, eventho I changed the prefix to uppercase:

```
const pref = "B";
const PREFIX = pref.toLowerCase() || pref.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Why you have an `||` there in the code ? What are exactly trying to do!

Comment: to explain that comment: `||` is the operator for logical or, so your code says `const PREFIX = the result of taking the logical or of pref.toLowerCase() and pref.toUpperCase()`, which doesn't really make much sense. That result is going to the the `toLowerCase()` result (because of how JS deals with logical operators. If the first thing in an `||` statement is true-ish, return that thing.)

Comment: some one told me that's what I should do to make my prefix works on lowercase and uppercase.

how should I changed it to make it work?

Comment: It doesn't make sense... if you want to change your prefix, use 'var' instead of 'const'. Your const PREFIX will always be true, pref.toLowerCase() has a value, so it's true. Same to pref.toUpperCase(). Please be clearer with your question.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want? Here is your code always you getting lower case value

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new, and it's kinda hard for me to follow.
but what I mean is.. when I type "bplay" and "Bplay" I want the bot to respond to me, and not just one of them..

Comment: where do you use `PREFIX` in your code?

Comment: I put my PREFIX on Index.js

Comment: it used to be like this before 
>const PREFIX ="b"
and then my my friend told me to change it to 
>const pref = "B";
const PREFIX = pref.toLowerCase() || pref.toUpperCase();
to make the bot respond on lowercase and uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do is to get the first character in the first word, and assign that to a variable. Then .toLowerCase() the variable and compare it to the lowercase prefix. If it returns true, do stuff. If not, return. It will look something like the following code.

```js
const prefix = "b";

//in the message event, assuming you have an argument handler
if(args[0].toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) {
//do stuff
} else {
//do nothing or return
}
```

What that does is turn the first word of the message to the lowercase form and check if it starts with the prefix. (also in lower case form when declared)
For example, the message is `Bping`, the code above turns it into `bping` and returns true in the `startsWith()` statement, as it startswith lowercase B.

Comment: IT WORKED! THANKS!
it's really easy to understand, even for a newbie like me.

Comment: glad to be of help :)